# Global Variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope, anonymous-function

I have a program where I use a global variable in an anonymous function. If I print my variable before the end of the function it is ok it has a value, but after the function it is empty.
This is my code, the global variable is "Mytree", it is just a parsin program of a csv file. Look at the end I do the 2 print.
My question is : why the value of my variable is not saved, and how to save it.

```
    // My program :
var Mytree = {}; // My global variable.
d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) { // The anonymous function to parse the csv file

    /* -- Parsing du csv -- */
    var dataTab = [];
    var j = 0;
    var exigence = "";
    var root = "Systeme";

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].Contrat !== "") {
            if (data[i].ExigenceContractuelle.split(".").length !== 1) {
                exigence = data[i].ExigenceContractuelle.split(".")[0];
                if (exigence.split("_").length !== 1) {
                    exigence = exigence.split("_")[0];
                }
            } else if (data[i].ExigenceContractuelle.split("-").length !== 1) {
                exigence = data[i].ExigenceContractuelle.split("-")[0];
            } else if (data[i].ExigenceContractuelle.split("_").lenght !== 1) {
                exigence = data[i].ExigenceContractuelle.split("_")[0];
            } else {
                exigence = data[i].ExigenceContractuelle.split(".")[0];
            }

            dataTab[j] = {
                name: data[i].ExigenceSystème,
                textExig: data[i].TexteExigence,
                validation: data[i].Validation,
                discution: data[i].Discution,
                SSSExig: data[i].LibelleTexte,
                team: root + "/" + exigence + "/" + data[i].ExigenceContractuelle
            };
            j++;
        }
    }
    /* -- -- */


    /* -- Tableau -> Json Tree -- */

    function fillTree(name, textExigTmp, SSSExigTmp, validation, discution, steps) {
        var current = null,
            existing = null,
            i = 0;
        for (var y = 0; y < steps.length; y++) {
            if (y === 0) {
                if (!Mytree.children || typeof Mytree.children === 'undefined') {
                    Mytree = {
                        text: steps[y],
                        textExig: textExigTmp,
                        SSSExig: SSSExigTmp,
                        leaf: false,
                        children: [],
                        open: false,
                        discution: discution == "" ? 0 : discution,
                        validation: validation == 1 ? true : false
                    };
                }
                current = Mytree.children;
            } else {
                existing = null;
                for (i = 0; i < current.length; i++) {
                    if (current[i].text === steps[y]) {
                        existing = current[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (existing) {
                    current = existing.children;
                } else {
                    current.push({
                        text: steps[y],
                        textExig: textExigTmp,
                        SSSExig: SSSExigTmp,
                        leaf: false,
                        children: [],
                        open: false,
                        discution: discution == "" ? 0 : discution,
                        validation: validation == 1 ? true : false
                    });
                    current = current[current.length - 1].children;
                }
            }
        }
        current.push({
            text: name,
            textExig: textExigTmp,
            SSSExig: SSSExigTmp,
            leaf: true,
            open: false,
            discution: discution == "" ? 0 : discution,
            validation: validation == 1 ? true : false
        });
    }

    for (x = 0; x < dataTab.length; x++) {
        steps = dataTab[x].team.split('/');
        fillTree(dataTab[x].name, dataTab[x].textExig, dataTab[x].SSSExig, dataTab[x].validation, dataTab[x].discution, steps);
    }
    /* -- -- */
    console.log(window.Mytree); // It's ok Mytree is not empty
});
console.log(window.Mytree); // Mytree = {} ...
```

Comment: JavaScript is asynchronous by nature, you cannot expect variables to have a certain state just because you access it at the end of the file. Try using a callback or a promise instead.

Comment: Here is a pretty good guide to asynchronous patterns in JavaScript (and how to tame them): http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript

Answer (score 0):

d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {  - is async operation. So, at first you see MyTree = {},
and in method - Mytree  with children.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not know when the anonymous function is being called..
it might be called async.